# UIImage on swift can't check for nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I have the following code on Swift

```
var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
        if image != nil {
           return image
       }
```

It used to work great, but now on Xcode Beta 6, this returns a warning

```
 'UIImage' is not a subtype of 'NSString'
```

I don't know what to do, I tried different things like

```
 if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            return image
   }
```

But the error changes to:

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
```

Is this a bug on Xcode6 beta 6 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you need to define the type manually: `var image:UIImage! = ...`.  Will try to track down the source.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, but the solution was to clean the build folder (⌘⇪K). On the off chance you have the same problem, you should try it.

Comment: I've had something similar in Obj-C. You could try replacing `image != nil` with `[image isNotEqualTo:nil]` or it's Swift version of that.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Update**

Swift now added the concept of failable initializers and UIImage is now one of them. The initializer returns an Optional so if the image cannot be created it will return nil.

---

Variables by default cannot be `nil`. That is why you are getting an error when trying to compare `image` to `nil`. You need to explicitly define your variable as [optional](http://drewag.me/posts/what-is-an-optional-in-swift):

```
let image: UIImage? = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
if image != nil {
   return image!
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "UIImage?" be inferred when using UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) since it can return nil?  "An initialized UIImage object, or nil if the method could not find the file or initialize the image from its contents."

Comment: Also, why my second try didn't work? afaik, if let x = y {} should work fine.

Comment: It seems could be a bug on Xcode beta 6, as seen on the changelog: "If you encounter a method for which the return value is incorrectly considered non-nullable, or a
property that is incorrectly considered non-nullable, you can work around the problem by
immediately wrapping the result in an optional:!
!
   var fooOpt: NSFoo? = object.reallyMightReturnNil()
   if let foo = fooOpt { ... }"

Comment: @Wak, this has been around since the first beta and is not what they are referring to with the change notes. They are well aware of it. The problem is that Swift objects never have optional construction. That doesn't translate well from Objective-C which can return `nil` from initialization. My solution is the current workaround. They may come up with a more elegant way to solve the problem in the future.

Comment: "failable", not "bailable" (although "bailable" does make a certain sense!)

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to check if an image  has content (> nil) is:

```
    if image.size.width != 0 { do someting}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func imageIsNullOrNot(imageName : UIImage)-> Bool
{

   let size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
   if (imageName.size.width == size.width)
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

the Above method call Like as :

```
 if (imageIsNullOrNot(selectedImage))
 {
     //image is not null
 }
 else
 {
    //image is null
 }
```

here, i check image size.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for it's width, which would be 0 if no image is uploaded.

```
if(image.size.width != 0){

      print("image found")

} else {

      print("image is null")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Init, that you are call `init?(contentsOfFile path: String)` the `?` means that it returns **optional** value.

You should check optional vars for `nil` before use it.

Shorter, than accepted answer and *Swift-style* way, than named **[Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)** to do that:

```swift
if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
   return image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it's imageAsset like this:

```
if image.imageAsset != nil
{
    // image is not null
}
else 
{
    //image is null
}
```